# A dictator tries to escape war by suspended animation, but travels too long, killed by maroonee

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Anthology story sought. A warlord, the Master? tries to escape capture by suspended animation, but last incoming rocket salvo seals his cave in mountains. Stays suspended for far longer than thought, woken by somebody who has been marooned alone for his views. When latter realises the evil of the Master he kills him, condemning himself to solitude for the rest of his life.

Comment: Sounds very broadly like Venor Vinge's Marooned In Realtime, but the details are wrong.

Comment: Thank you all very much for the help. There is nothing like losing a well loved story, and being haunted by vague recollections

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This is [*Exile of the Eons*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exile_of_the_Eons) by Arthur C. Clarke.

The wikipedia summary contains many elements that match your story;

> The first part of the story opens in a near future world, at the
>   climax of a devastating world war, in which “The Master”, a
>   Hitler-like figure, has tried and failed to dominate the world by
>   military force. As the enemy closes in on his last stronghold in the
>   Himalayas, the Master seals himself in a suspended animation chamber
>   buried deep in the mountains. He intends to hibernate for one hundred
>   years, after which he assumes that his enemies will have forgotten
>   about him, and then resume his plans for world domination. However, a
>   freak accident disables the mechanism which is supposed to revive him
>   automatically, and the Master remains in suspended animation for
>   billions of years while geological forces reshape the planet above
>   him.
>
> The second part of the story skips ahead to the far future when
>   humanity has colonized the stars. Trevindor the Philosopher commits
>   the unprecedented act of challenging the political and philosophical
>   orthodoxy of this peaceful but uniform galaxy-spanning civilization,
>   where dissent, criminality, violence and any form of conflict, are all
>   virtually unknown. Instead of promising to give up his unorthodoxy,
>   Trevindor chooses exile into future time, when the Sun is entering its
>   red giant phase, and Earth is a parched, virtually lifeless desert.
>   Trevindor explores the dying Earth, and has almost resigned himself to
>   spending the rest of his life in isolation, when he finds the Master's
>   hibernaculum, now exposed on the surface by millennia of erosion.
>
> In the last part of the story, the two strands come together;
>   Trevindor enters the chamber, and his presence apparently triggers the
>   Master's revival. The Master is shocked to find another person in the
>   chamber with him – more so when it becomes apparent that Trevindor can
>   read his mind, and thinks there nothing unusual about telepathy. The
>   Master begins to suspect the truth of what has happened, but Trevindor
>   has also learned the truth about the Master – and he must now choose
>   whether to share his exile with a man of almost inhuman barbarism, or
>   to commit an act of inhuman barbarism himself.

Comment: The whole story an be read at https://archive.org/stream/Super_Science_Stories_v06n03_1950-03#page/n85/mode/2up.

Comment: Read this as a kid and was mightily impressed, even if I didn't know about Hitler, Stalin, Mao, Ghengis or whomever, nor even about WWII. _"We do not know if civilization will still exist in the age in which you find yourself. Man may now be extinct since the Chromosome K Star K will have become dominant and the race may have mutated into something no longer human. That is for you to discover."_ Clearly there is no Bene Gesserit around.

Comment: Thank you all very much. Appreciated.